# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'barh'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a GUI interface using PyQt5. I made  a class that is responsible for plotting a categorical column using `value_counts()` into bar chart. It   will receive the data frame called `tb1` and the column name from called `ctb1`.

this is a piece of my code:

```
class Ui_Dialog:
   def setupUi(self, Dialog):
       Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
       Dialog.resize(900, 500)

   def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "output window"))

class Canvas(FigureCanvas):
   def __init__(self,parent=None, width=10, height=9):
       fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height))
       self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
       FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
       self.setParent(parent)

     

   def plot(self,df1,ctb1,v2):
       CountStatus = pd.value_counts(df1[ctb1].values, sort=True)
       CountStatus.axes.barh()
       self.draw()
       

class Dialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Dialog):

   def __init__(self,tb1,ctb1,parent=None):
       super().__init__(parent)
       self.setupUi(self)
       self.canvas = Canvas(self,width=8, height=5)
       self.canvas.plot(tb1,ctb1,v2)
       self.canvas.move(0, 0)


if __name__ == "__main__":
# some code here
```

I'm trying to put it in my subplot which called `axes` using this `CountStatus.axes.barh()` but it keeps giving me

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'barh'

I can't understand what seems the problem or is there another way to plot it into a bar chart?

Comment: The error is explicit: `CountStatus.axes` is a list.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.axes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused between your `self.axes` which indeed are matplotlib `Axes`, to `pd.value_counts.axes` which are just a list of the labels of the `value_counts` series.

same name but completely **different and unrelated** objects.

Instead use something like `self.axes.barh(CountStatus...)`
or `CountSatus.plot.barh(ax=self.axes)`

Comment: thank you for your response I try it with   ` self.axes.barh(CountStatus,width=0.5)` it gave me  `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' should I convert the count status into two arrays one for x and the other for labels?

Comment: This is one option. Another option is to CountSatus.plot.barh(ax=self.axes)

Comment: @LiorCohen you should include that in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this peace of code:

```
 def plot(self,df1,ctb1,v2):          
     CountStatus = pd.value_counts(df1[ctb1].values, sort=True)
     CountStatus.plot.barh(ax=self.axes)
     self.draw()
```